# Will a spin off be recognized if it follows the branding guidelines?

Tags: legal

http://design.ubuntu.com/audiences

> There are more than 3 options
>
> For example, we consider the Desktop CD to be 50% Canonical, but the
>   Server CD to be 80% Canonical. Your own Ubuntu remix CD’s might be
>   100% community. Pick an appropriate position that reflects accurately
>   how much of the work was done by the Ubuntu community and how much by
>   Canonical. If your work is part of the official project and represents
>   the trademark, include some element of Canonical to indicate that. For
>   example: an unofficial LoCo blog would be 100% community, but the
>   Official Ubuntu Book would be 20% Canonical.

According to the quote above, Ubuntu will recognize any spin-off of it as long as its branding is appropriate, right? If so, what does one do for his remix of Ubuntu (his current setup of the OS) to be recognized and distributed?

Comment: That link is not about spin-offs from the Ubuntu distribution but Ubuntu brand guidelines so that sites like this one can be recognised as part of the Ubuntu community project without claiming to represent the owners of Ubuntu - Canonical. So, the answer to your question is, No. You need Canonical's permission to use Canonical trademarks (even the name Ubuntu) in any spin-off as you call it.

Answer (score 5):

The page you should be studying is this one:

[Trademark policy - Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/aboutus/trademarkpolicy)

It is a long document but note these selected quotations.

> **Community advocacy**. Ubuntu is built by, and largely for, its
>   community. We share access to the Trademarks with the entire community
>   for the purposes of discussion, development and advocacy. We recognise
>   that most of the open source discussion and development areas are for
>   non-commercial purposes and will allow the use of the trademarks in
>   this context, provided:

Please see the provisions listed that must be complied with.

> **Derived works**. The ability to customise Ubuntu to meet your specific
>   needs is one of the great strengths of free software in general, and
>   Ubuntu in particular. While we encourage customisation and derivation
>   of Ubuntu, we must balance that freedom with the integrity of the
>   Trademarks and the quality which they represent. To help reach that
>   balance, we have established the following guidelines and definitions.

Please read the guidelines and definitions. It is a section that is too long to be quoted.

> **Building on Ubuntu or for Ubuntu**. If you are producing new software
>   which is intended for use with or on Ubuntu, you may use the Trademark
>   in a way which indicates the intent of your product. For example, if
>   you are developing a system management tool for Ubuntu, acceptable
>   project titles would be "System Management for Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu
>   Based Systems Management". We would strongly discourage, and likely
>   would consider to be problematic, a name such as UbuntuMan, Ubuntu
>   Management, ManBuntu, etc. Furthermore, you may not use the Trademarks
>   in a way which implies an endorsement where that doesn't exist, or
>   which attempts to unfairly or confusingly capitalise on the goodwill
>   or brand of the project.
>
> **Commentary and parody**. The Ubuntu trademarks are designed to cover use
>   of a mark to imply origin or endorsement by the project. When a user
>   downloads something called Ubuntu, they should know it comes from the
>   Ubuntu project. This helps Ubuntu build a reputation that will not be
>   damaged by confusion around what is, and isn't, Ubuntu. Using the
>   trademarks in your discussion, commentary, criticism or parody, in
>   ways that unequivocally do not imply endorsement, is permissible.
>   Anyone is free to write articles, create websites, blog about, or talk
>   about Ubuntu -- as long as it's clear to everyone -- including people
>   completely unfamiliar with Ubuntu -- that they are simply referring to
>   Ubuntu and in no way speaking for Canonical, or the Ubuntu project.

There is a further section called: **Restricted use that requires a trademark licence**

It is a long section and an individual wishing to make use of Ubuntu in a way that you indicate you wish to use Ubuntu should study that page.

Just noted an important point:

> as long as it's clear to everyone -- including people
>   completely unfamiliar with Ubuntu -- that they are simply referring to
>   Ubuntu and in no way speaking for Canonical, or the Ubuntu project.

So for the record, I am in no way speaking for Canonical or the Ubuntu project. I am merely directing your attention to information provide by Canonical.

Comment: Agreed.  I think the question is mostly about re-branding.